# random variable and conditional probability

Tags: probability

Three balls are randomly chosen from an urn containing 3 white, 3 red, and 5 black balls. Suppose that we win $\$1$ for each white ball selected and lose $\$1$ for each red ball selected. If we let X denote our total winnings from the experiment, then X is a random variable taking on the possible values 0, $\pm1, \pm 2, \pm 3$ with respective probabilities. Let $E$ be the event that we win something. We want to find the probability that we win $i$ dollars given that we win something. We have

$$ P( \{X = i \} | E ) = \frac{ P( \{ X = i \} \cap E \})}{P(E)} = \frac{P(X=i) }{P(E)} $$

Since $E \subset \{ X = i \}$. Is this correct formulation?

Comment: Yes, the formulation is correct (since, effectivelly, $E=\{X=1\}\cup\{X=2\}\cup\{X=3\}$).